# DynamoDB Query / Scan with combined conditions

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I am facing an architectural problem (or a logical one) and am not sure what is the best way to proceed. I am building a small matchmaking app to study AWS Mobile HUB and it's services and get a bit more familiar with it.

My DynamoDB contains a table with `rendezvous` that have the following 2 properties (and some more which are not important here):

```
Rendezvous

- from_gender
- interest_gender
```

Additionally i am using cognito and have my users have a property

```
User

- usr_gender
- interest_gender
```

Basically I want to match up users that are interested in `from_gender` and possess a gender of `interest_gender`

At the moment, `User` can be either `male` or `female` whereas `interest_gender` can be either `male`, `female` or `all`.

This means for a user we have 6 combinations:

```
Gender -> Interested In

Male -> female 
Female -> female 
Female -> all 
Male -> all 
Male -> male
Female -> male
```

Now it gets tricky:

**Example**

User A (`female` interested in `all`) is looking for `rendezvous`

She should be shown the 4 following rendezvous types:

```
from_gender, interest_gender

male, female
male, all
female, female
female, all
```

which means that I would need a query of sorts (dummycode):

> rendevous.query("
>
> (from_gender = male) AND ((interest_gender = female") OR (interest_gender = all)) OR
>
> (from_gender = female) AND ((interest_gender = female") OR (interest_gender = all))
>
> ")

**However**

I have not yet found a way to get this working with query or scan as they do not support OR queries on the same property.

**I tried** 
to create indeces (using codes for the different combinations, but i did not find a way to create a queryable index for all cases), **note** that additionally to this interest I would also need to sort by age (between min / max) and location min/max lat, min/max long.

Are there any smart approaches using DynamoDB or am I forced to go the SQL route?

**This is the query expression I have tried latest: Works**

```
func generateScanExpression() -> AWSDynamoDBScanExpression {
    let usr = UserHelper.sharedHelper.currentUser
    let expression = AWSDynamoDBScanExpression()
    expression.limit = 10

    // Male interested in male
    if (usr?.interest == Constants.CONST_MALE) && (usr?.gender == Constants.CONST_MALE){
        expression.filterExpression = "details_fromGender = :fg AND ( match_interest = :ig OR match_interest = :all )"
        expression.expressionAttributeValues = [":fg": Constants.CONST_MALE, ":ig": Constants.CONST_MALE, ":all": Constants.CONST_ALL ]
    }
    // Female interested in female
    if (usr?.interest == Constants.CONST_FEMALE) && (usr?.gender == Constants.CONST_FEMALE){
        expression.filterExpression = "details_fromGender = :fg AND ( match_interest = :ig OR match_interest = :all )"
        expression.expressionAttributeValues = [":fg": Constants.CONST_FEMALE, ":ig": Constants.CONST_FEMALE, ":all": Constants.CONST_ALL ]
    }
    // Male interested in female
    if (usr?.interest == Constants.CONST_FEMALE) && (usr?.gender == Constants.CONST_MALE){
        expression.filterExpression = "details_fromGender = :fg AND ( match_interest = :ig OR match_interest = :all )"
        expression.expressionAttributeValues = [":fg": Constants.CONST_FEMALE, ":ig": Constants.CONST_MALE, ":all": Constants.CONST_ALL ]
    }
    // Female interested in male
    if (usr?.interest == Constants.CONST_MALE) && (usr?.gender == Constants.CONST_FEMALE){
        expression.filterExpression = "details_fromGender = :fg AND ( match_interest = :ig OR match_interest = :all )"
        expression.expressionAttributeValues = [":fg": Constants.CONST_MALE, ":ig": Constants.CONST_FEMALE, ":all": Constants.CONST_ALL ]
    }
    // Male interested in all
    if (usr?.interest == Constants.CONST_ALL) && (usr?.gender == Constants.CONST_MALE){
        expression.filterExpression = "( details_fromGender = :fg OR details_fromGender = :all ) AND match_interest = :ig"
        expression.expressionAttributeValues = [":fg": Constants.CONST_MALE, ":ig": Constants.CONST_MALE ]
    }
    // Female interested in all
    if (usr?.interest == Constants.CONST_ALL) && (usr?.gender == Constants.CONST_FEMALE){
        expression.filterExpression = "( details_fromGender = :fg OR details_fromGender = :all ) AND match_interest = :ig"
        expression.expressionAttributeValues = [":fg": Constants.CONST_MALE, ":ig": Constants.CONST_FEMALE ]
    }

    return expression
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you absolutely certain you can't use an `OR` condition on a DynamoDB `scan` operation? I'm not saying you're wrong, I just seem to remember doing it. Here is some code I would try if I were working on the same issue:

```
func findMatches(interestGender: String, userGender: String, allCondition: String, map: AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper) -> AWSTask<AnyObject> {
    let scan = AWSDynamoDBScanExpression()
    scan.filterExpression = "interest_gender = :interestGender AND usr_gender = :userGender OR interest_gender = :allCondition"
    scan.expressionAttributeValues = [":interest_gender":interestGender, ":usr_gender":userGender, ":interest_gender":allCondition]

    return map.scan(Rendezvous.self, expression: scan).continue({ (task: AWSTask) -> AnyObject? in
        if (task.error != nil) {
            print(task.error)
        }

        if (task.exception != nil){
            print(task.exception)
        }

        if let result = task.result {
            return result.items as! [Rendezvous] as AnyObject?
        }

        return nil
    })

}
```

This would assume that you have your `Rendezvous` object that conforms to `AWSDynamoDBObjectModel` and `AWSDynamoDBModeling`. Try it, and let me know if it works for you, otherwise I'll delete my answer. I don't have the ability to test it for you until much later tonight, so I'm not 100% certain it will work.

Comment: i will have to check tomorrow as well, I am quite certain but not 100%, my attempts so far failed. will try out with your sample :) thank you !

Comment: it actually works, thank you! i updated my final query to the question for reference.

Comment: @SebastianFluckiger - I'm so glad that works for you! Good to know! Best of luck